# Mocked function is not called, instead is used real function

Tags: java, spring, mocking, mockito

I started to study mocking. I want that test will fail when is called (only for study purpose).

MathUtils class:

```
public class MathUtils {

  public int addWithHelper(int a, int b) {
        MathUtilsHelper mathUtilsHelper = new MathUtilsHelper();
        return mathUtilsHelper.addNumbers(a,b);
    }
}
```

And my MathUtilsHelper:

```
public class MathUtilsHelper {

     int addNumbers(int a, int b) {
         return a + b;
     }
}
```

Class MathUtilsTest

```
@Test
void itShouldAddNumberFromHelper() {

     MathUtilsHelper mathUtilsHelperMocked = Mockito.mock(MathUtilsHelper.class);
     when(mathUtilsHelperMocked.addNumbers(5,3)).thenReturn(999); // this doesn't works !!!!!!

     int add = mathUtils.add(5, 3);
     assertEquals(8, add); // should throw error

}
```

Thank you for any help!

Comment: `MathUtils` doesn't have the mock instance of `MathUtilsHelper` that you created. It has its own instance of `MathUtilsHelper` that it created itself using `new MathUtilsHelper()`. This is why we use dependency injection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MathUtils doesn't have the mocked object in it, you do as follows for MathUtils class:

```
public class MathUtils {
  public MathUtilsHelper mathUtilsHelper;

  public MathUtils(MathUtilsHelper mathUtilsHelper ){
     this.mathUtilsHelper=mathUtilsHelper;
  }

  public int addWithHelper(int a, int b) {
     return mathUtilsHelper.addNumbers(a,b);
  }
}
```

And when initializing your test try this:

```
@Test
void itShouldAddNumberFromHelper() {

   MathUtilsHelper mathUtilsHelperMocked = Mockito.mock(MathUtilsHelper.class);
   when(mathUtilsHelperMocked.addNumbers(5,3)).thenReturn(999);
   mathUtils= new MathUtils(mathUtilsHelperMocked);

   int add = mathUtils.addWithHelper(5, 3);
   assertEquals(8, add);

}
```

Comment: Thank you for showing me the code, but it still shows that test passed. Expected value isn't 999.

Comment: The name of the method call in the test was wrong, now it is correct (add -> addWithHelper). I have tested the code it works fine with me. Please check more your actual code with given.

Answer (score 1):

Your util class is creating a new instance of your helper each time, so will never use the mock.

I'm not sure why you need the util class to be honest, but if you want to make it easier to test, change it so that an instance of the helper is passed in on the constructor rather than instantiating it in the util class. Dependency injection in other words.

That way you can create the mock, and create an instance of the util class by passing in the mock.

Comment: Ok, now it makes sense. So when I want to use @Autowired (in regular application) I should always used with constructor and not with field, right?

Comment: Constructor injection is recommended as it means you can't create an object that doesn't have a dependency set, which you can do with setter injection. Also if you're using Spring and only have a single constructor taking in other dependencies that are Spring beans, you can leave the autowired annotation off altogether, which is handy.